# How should I implement the function to choose the route i want?

Tags: anylogic

I have a simple network that has several routes from start to end. Vehicles from a transporter fleet will carry agents from the left conveyor to the right conveyor using the moveByTransporter block. What are some syntax i can use to refer to paths/nodes on the network?

Also, what is a sample code line of how i can check the number of vehicles on a specific path?

This is my sample network and idea of trying how to make a new routing instead of just the shortest path (the path i want to follow is via the yellow highlighted one)

[image]

Comment: For a simple routing algorithm take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm that use greedy approach. For congestion I would recommend to take a look at Bellman-Ford algorithm.

Comment: Could you also introduce how i can refer to the paths in the model? I am having trouble with the syntax as im quite new.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The moveTo block will take the route with the shortest distance.  If the agent's speed is the same across all choices, then the shortest distance will also be the fastest time.

In the past, I have used Dijkstra's algorithm and manually routed my agents from a to b, then b to c, etc.  This way, I could use travel times instead of just distances.  This also opens up the possibility of considering congestion by applying a penalty to some segments if there are too many other agents on them.  You can also pick a route, but then when you get to the next node, re-calculate the rest of the route for updated congestion considerations.

This is all custom, and I would not recommend it for simple problems.  You would be better off to look at other alternatives (assume constant speeds or consider the pedestrian library with walls, etc, depending on your problem).

Comment: Is there any tutorial where I can educate myself on how to take into consideration the number of vehicles/agents on the paths/nodes? I am unfamiliar with the syntax and cannot seem to be able to find it on Anylogic Help.

Comment: Can anyone suggest something for me? :)

Comment: Samuel, AnyLgoic uses Java code. Custom routing algorithm should create a list of paths with Java code. To learn Java you may use any online tutorial in the web, there are a lot of tutorials. Most of AnyLogic tutorials have Java code snippets, follow to the tutorials from Help - AnyLogic Help Tutorials (e.g. Job Shop or Air Defence). Also Help provides Java basics with set of articles in the respective section. There is online help at help.anylogic.com

Comment: Hi @Gregory, thanks for your response, I'll check out the Job Shop and Air Defence examples on how i can implement custom routing!